# Script# and System.IO.Stream

Tags: c#, stream, script#

I'm currently working on getting the C# Source for the 7-Zip compression library to compile on Script# but facing the problem that System.IO.Stream is not supported in Script#'s version of the BCL. Any suggestions how to handle this?

Comment: Implementing your own Stream, seems like the obvious thing to do (might be some work - which is probably why it isn't included already).

Comment: Stream is an abstract class, with a number of implementations. What specific stream subclass(es) are you hoping to use? This may help guide a better answer here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could theoretically define a Stream and implement on your end over an array of numbers corresponding to the bytes - script isn't all that great at dealing with byte sequences however (until we get typed arrays in script).

Streams aren't that commonly used within script code - typically you have a text response for example from an XHR request, or a base64-encoded string for image data from a canvas element (some typical cases where you might have expected streams). Hence they're not there out-of-the-box.

If you do define one, perhaps you can share your work. If you think the 7-zip compression you have is general purpose enough, and publicly shareable, would love to discuss further. As you hopefully know, script# is on github, and would be interesting to see an ecosystem of community contributions and extensions.